# How to get Row Count in table in Oracle RDS

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table as follows...

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
TRANS_TYPE_CD | Member_ID | POINT_ACCOUNT_TYPE |  TRANS_DTM
--------------------------------------------------------------
Debit         | 1702      | 10                 | 2018-12-04
Credit        | 1702      | 10                 | 2018-12-04
Debit         | 1702      | 10                 | 2018-12-04
Debit         | 1702      | 10                 | 2018-12-04
Debit         | 1702      | 10                 | 2018-12-04
------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now I want select data from this table with row count. 
For that purpose, I am using this SQL...

```
select rowNumber, trans_dtm, lower(trans_type_cd) as trans_type_cd
from   (
        select pttrans.trans_dtm, pttrans.trans_type_cd
             , row_number() over (partition by trans_dtm order by trans_dtm desc ) as rowNumber
        from   (
                 select * from point_trans
                 where  member_id = 1702
                 and    point_account_type = 10 
                 and    (point_type_cd is null or point_type_cd not in ('Hold' ,'RolledBack','Rolledback'))
                 and    trans_dtm between to_date('2014-06-30', 'yyyy-mm-dd') and to_date('2018-12-04', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
               ) pttrans
        fetch first 300 rows only
       )
where rowNumber between 1 and 10
order by trans_dtm desc;
```

But in output, as rowNumber I am getting 1 always.... and that is why "rowNumber between 1 and 10" clause is not working properly...

The result I am getting ...

```
rowNumber | TRANS_DTM   | TRANS_TYPE_CD
-----------------------------------------
1         | 2018-12-04 | debit
1         | 2018-12-04 | debit
1         | 2018-12-04 | debit
1         | 2018-12-04 | credit
-----------------------------------------
```

Can any one help me out with proper SQL. My requirement is simply to get the row number and filter out the rows depending on param.

I am using AWS Oracle RDS....

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I would remove `PARTITION BY` `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by TRANS_DTM DESC ) `

Comment: select rowNumber,TRANS_DTM, LOWER(TRANS_TYPE_CD) as TRANS_TYPE_CD from ( select ptTrans.TRANS_DTM, ptTrans.TRANS_TYPE_CD, ROW_NUMBER()  AS rowNumber from ( select * from point_trans where member_id = 1702 and POINT_ACCOUNT_TYPE = 10 
and (point_type_cd is NULL or point_type_cd not in ('Hold' ,'RolledBack','Rolledback')) and TRANS_DTM between TO_DATE('2014-06-30', 'yyyy-mm-dd') 
and TO_DATE('2018-12-04', 'yyyy-mm-dd') ) ptTrans 
fetch first 300 rows only ) WHERE rowNumber between 1 and 10 order by TRANS_DTM DESC   , but this is giving error "missing window specification for this function"

Comment: Sorry , got your point , and its working now .... thanks a lot

Comment: @Biswajit .  . You should delete the question if it is answered in a comment.

Comment: Do the `trans_dtm` values have a time component? If you are partitioning by `trans_dtm` then `2018-12-04 00:00:01` is not the same as `2018-12-04 00:00:02` and so will be reported in a separate row.

Comment: yes , got the issue @WilliamRobertson